# Retrieve values of multidimentional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

Im not able to retrieve all the data from this multidimensional array. I have coded using foreach loop but it shows error as the inner loop isnt working out fine.. Please help me.

This is the code I have tried

```
 foreach($capture as $k) {
    foreach($k['ReportLines'] as $detail){

         echo $detail['Quantity'];
         echo $k['Description'];
   }
   }
```

This is the array

```
  $capture=  Array
(

[ReportLines] => 
    Array([0] => 
        Array(

            [Quantity] => 4.00

                    [Item] => MISPM
                            [Description] => Midnight
                            [Price] => 30.00
                            [Amount] => 120.00
                         )

                  [1] => 
        Array(

            [Quantity] => 40.00

                    [Item] => BMISPM
                            [Description] => Midnight2
                            [Price] => 340.00
                            [Amount] => 1220.00
                         )
                  [2] => 
        Array(

            [Quantity] => 24.00

                    [Item] => AMISPM
                            [Description] => Midnight3
                            [Price] => 3250.00
                            [Amount] => 1220.00
                         )
                  ([3] => 
        Array(

            [Quantity] => 34.00

                    [Item] => MIeSPM
                            [Description] => Midnight
                            [Price] => 30.00
                            [Amount] => 120.00
                         )
    )
```

)

Comment: What about `$detail['Item']['Description']`?

Comment: You should include the error you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
foreach($capture['ReportLines'] as $detail) { 
    echo $detail['Quantity'];
    echo $detail['Description'];
}
```

Sorry for fast response but i'm writing from phone.

I will edit the answer as soon as possible